# Alfa Awus036h or other solution to amplify wifi signal?

Tags: wireless-networking, signal

Before I shell out €45 to get the [Alfa Awus036h](http://www.data-alliance.net/-strse-73/Alfa-500mW-AWUS036H-USB/Detail.bok) USB device (500mW or 1000mW?) to increase my odds of connecting to a remote wifi network, I'd like to get some user feedback about this device, and if there are other options (same type, or eg. one that connects through the Ethernet port).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strength of a wifi signal depends on both the sender and the receiver, so buying an adapter that has a very strong output signal will make the router have better reception, but in order to get the computer to have a higher signal without changing the output level of the router usually means a bigger antenna.

If you know the direction of the signal and are looking for a cheaper alternative, you could build a simple directional [antenna from a can of Pringles](http://www.oreillynet.com/cs/weblog/view/wlg/448) (yes, the potato chip can). Of course, this requires your current wifi adapter to have a removable antenna.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. For those having the same issue, and provided the Pringles solution didn't work, consider getting a shielded USB cable and a USB wifi key so you can leave the USB key outside the window and see if you're getting a better signal.